# how to make rectangle scale vertically animation in Raphael JS

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, raphael

The Raphael Js website is down so I can't find any documentation or anything on how to do this. I want to create a rectangle with initial vertical size of 0 and make it animate so that it gets vertically larger and larger when I click another object. Thanks!

so i've got a rectangle

```
var water = paper.rect( 0, 300, 600, 0).attr({fill:"blue"});
```

how do I make it animate?

Comment: The Raphael.js library has moved from [http://raphaeljs.com](http://raphaeljs.com) to [http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/).

Answer (score 0):

In particular, check out the documentation for

- [Element.attribute()](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/reference.html#Element.attr),
- [Element.animate()](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/reference.html#Element.animate),
- [Element.click()](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/reference.html#Element.click), and
- [Raphael.animation()](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/reference.html#Raphael.animation).

The following snippet demonstrates a simple animation like the one you are looking for. Click the red square to make the water "fill". It may not work in some browsers (e.g. Chrome) possibly because the snippet is trying to access an external third-party library, i.e. Raphael.js. So, to run it, either go to this SO question/answer page on Firefox or copy the code and run it on your own computer.

Note that, to make the water "fill" in the up direction, you can't just increase the height of the water rectangle...that would make the rectangle grow downwards. You also have to simultaneously raise the top of the rectangle by the identical amount. Thus you have to animate `height` and `y` simultaneously, as shown in the code.

*UPDATE: provided an up-to-date link for the Raphael minified library*

```js
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 500, 120);
var button = paper.rect( 10, 10, 40, 20).attr({fill:"red"});
var water = paper.rect( 10, 100, 400, 0).attr({fill:"blue"});
var anim = Raphael.animation({
  height: 60,
  y: (100 - 60)
}, 2000);
button.click(function() {water.animate(anim);});
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/master/raphael.min.js"></script>
```

To get the animation to start, click on the red rectangle.